# RESTful URI to get the next/previous resource

Tags: api, rest, resources

I have an application based on articles. An API is providing the articles informations via the following URI:

```
/articles
/articles/{articleId}
```

So far so good. Now the problem I have is from a singular article page I would like to have the ability to go to the **next** or the **previous** article.

From where the user stands, the application is only aware of the current article information.(i.g. `{"article": {"id": 5, "title": "My Article"}}`Do not focus on the ID as the logic to get the previous or the next article wouldn't be just a matter of -1 / +1)

Unless I am wrong, I am not expecting to have within `/articles/5` the informations of the next and previous article. That leaves me one solution, **having a resource that is aware of the current article and its next and previous.**

Would it be?:

`1. /articles/5/pager`
`2. /articles/5/pager?next=3&previous=3`

1. would be getting the default pager setting from article 5 and return 1 previous and 1 next
2. would be the next 3 articles from article 5 and the previous 3 articles

Does is makes sense to have the pager resource?
Something else?
Is mixin plural/singular valid as well?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd use a HTML representation of your resource you'd usually just add a link to the next and previous article. The same can be done if you're using a JSON representation:

```
{
   "article" : {
      "id" : 5,
      "title" : "My Article",
      "links" : [
         {
            "href" : "/articles/0815",
            "rel" : "previous"
         },
         {
            "href" : "/articles/4711",
            "rel" : "next"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: From the frontend application this structure does makes sense but from someone calling the API, I am not convinced... Returning the next and previous article within `/articles/5` seems like it is having too many responsibilities to me.

Comment: @Niao do some research on HATEOAS. You'll see the content of this answer is pretty common practice. (+1)

Comment: Or take a look at the [Hypertext Application Language](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html).

Comment: What if the "next" resource is deleted while the link to that "next" item was in the view state? How to recover from that error? Now the "next" item is unknown to the view. So also from the fronted applications point of view this seems to be fairly error prone. Am I missing something?

Comment: The server should return a `404` or `410` or redirect with a `3xx` status code. But this is not related to the question and can happen to every request.